Group an Excel table in up to seven levels
I have Excel tables to group, to work further with them. The content of the tables comes from software, where the content was divided tree-like in up to seven levels.
I want to rebuild this structure in Excel via VBA.
In the tables the level of each row is written in column A:

In the end it should be structured like in the software:

The result I need:

My code:
Sub GRUPPIEREN()
Dim mainWB  As Workbook
Dim xlFileName As String

Set mainWB = ThisWorkbook

' Schritt 2: Iterate durch Zeilen und apply groups
With mainWB.Sheets("TEST")

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Stukturebenen als Variablen
Dim Ebene1 As Long
Dim Ebene2 As Long
Dim Ebene3 As Long
Dim Ebene4 As Long
Dim Ebene5 As Long

' find firsts
Dim start As Long
Dim Ebene As Long
Dim Offset As Long
Offset = 0
    
For i = 2 To LastRow
    Ebene = .Range("A" & i).Value
    If Ebene = 1 Then
        Ebene1 = i
        End If
    If Ebene = 2 Then
        Ebene2 = i
        End If
    If Ebene = 3 Then
       Ebene3 = i
        End If
    If Ebene = 4 Then
       Ebene4 = i
        End If
    If Ebene = 5 Then
       Ebene5 = i
       start = i + 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = start To LastRow
    ' check format
    Ebene = .Range("A" & i).Value
        ' Ebene 1
        If Ebene = 1 Then
            If ((i - Ebene1) > 1) Then
                ' Neue Gruppe 1
                .Rows((Ebene1) & ":" & (i - 1)).Group
                ' leere row fuer verschachtelte Gliederung
                'OLD:.Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
            
            Ebene1 = i + 1
            Offset = 0
        End If
        ' Ebene 2
        If Ebene = 2 Then
            If ((i - Ebene2) > 1) Then
                ' Neue Gruppe 2
                .Rows((Ebene2 + 1) & ":" & (i - 1 - Offset)).Group
            End If
            Offset = 0
            Ebene2 = i
        End If
        ' Ebene 3
        If Ebene = 3 Then
            If ((i - Ebene3) > 1) Then
                ' Neue Gruppe 3
                .Rows((Ebene3 + 1) & ":" & (i - 1 - Offset)).Group
            End If
            Offset = 0
            Ebene3 = i
        End If
        ' Ebene 4
        If Ebene = 4 Then
            If ((i - Ebene4) > 1) Then
                ' Neue Gruppe 4
                .Rows((Ebene4 + 1) & ":" & (i - 1 - Offset)).Group
            End If
            Offset = 0
            Ebene4 = i
        End If
        ' Ebene 5
        If Ebene = 5 Then
            If ((.Range("A" & i).Value - Ebene5) > 1) Then
                ' Neue Gruppe 5
                .Rows((Ebene5 + 1) & ":" & (i - 1 - Offset)).Group
            End If
            Offset = 0
            Ebene5 = i
        End If
Next i

' Schritt 3: Schliesse uebrige Gruppen ab
' Ebene 1
If (((LastRow + 1) - Ebene1) > 1) Then
    ' Neue Gruppe 1
    .Rows((Ebene1) & ":" & (LastRow)).Group
    ' leere row fuer verschachtelte Gliederung
    'OLD:.Rows((LastRow + 1) & ":" & (LastRow + 1)).EntireRow.Insert
End If

' Ebene 2
If (((LastRow + 1) - Ebene2) > 1) Then
    ' Neue Gruppe 2
    .Rows((Ebene2 + 1) & ":" & (LastRow)).Group
End If
' Ebene 3
If (((LastRow + 1) - Ebene3) > 1) Then
    ' Neue Gruppe 3
    .Rows((Ebene3 + 1) & ":" & (LastRow)).Group
End If
' Ebene 4
If (((LastRow + 1) - Ebene4) > 1) Then
    ' Neue Gruppe 4
    .Rows((Ebene4 + 1) & ":" & (LastRow)).Group
End If
' Ebene 5
If (((LastRow + 1) - Ebene5) > 1) Then
    ' Neue Gruppe 5
    .Rows((Ebene5 + 1) & ":" & (LastRow)).Group
End If
End With 

End Sub

It groups up to the 5th level, but the first Group on Level 1 is one row too high:

I think level 5 is good, but all others don't find the right end:


About the table: it has about 9000 rows and there are 10-11 elements on level 1 each with the levels 2 up to 7 below

I want to rebuild this structure in Excel via VBA. Welcome to SO. Please, post the code you've developed, what errors are you getting or where are you stuck.

Thank you for the hint! :) I added my code, but honestly I'm a bit ashamed of it. Unfortunately, the topic is probably too complex for me as a beginner, but I would really like to learn.

No reason to be ashamed of your code. We all write terrible code all the time, and this code you posted looks better than most VBA posted here. I'm curious why you have an .EntireRow.Insert() in your logic. Looking at your desired results, I don't see any reason why you would want an extra blank row submitted. You seem to not want that row inserted but still have that line of code present. Is that a mistake?

Thank you! Yes that was an mistake :) The Code comes from an other table, where something similar was done but with an other structure.
In my case I don't want these blank rows. I deactivated it and they disappeared. First problem solved! :)

Pls try.
Sub MultiLevelGroup()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, iVal As Long, iEnd As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    ' Get the last row#
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
        ' Clear outline
        .ClearOutline
        .Parent.Outline.SummaryRow = xlSummaryAbove
        ' Load data into an array
        arrData = .Value
    End With
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To LastRow - 1
        If arrData(i, 1) < arrData(i + 1, 1) Then
            iVal = arrData(i, 1)
            iEnd = 0
            ' Locate the end of each group
            For j = i + 2 To LastRow
                If arrData(j, 1) <= iVal Then
                    iEnd = j - 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If iEnd = 0 Then iEnd = LastRow
            If iEnd >= i + 1 Then
                ' Group rows
                Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(iEnd, 1)).Rows.Group
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Group method (Excel)


Range.ClearOutline method (Excel)


Outline.SummaryRow property (Excel)



My child is sick today, so I can only test the code briefly at the moment. But it seems to work! Thank you very much!!! I'll try to understand what you've written there later.
On the frist view it also seems to work for more than 5 levels, right?

Yes. But don't forget 8 is the limit of Excel. Microsoft documentation:

Choose an account

